# Loop keeps overwriting value of update("$max") in java for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have loop that iterates through the events that happened in one hour. Each event has fields called floor and height. My task is to get the maximum value of height for each floor. I'd appreciate some advise. Also I was wondering if that's possible using max method from update.

I tried using max method from update, however, when loop keeps iterating maxHeight keeps being over written.
Also I tried to have some class variable that will hold the value of maxHeight that I need, however, maxHeight should be unique for each floor, and using global variable returns maxHeight among all the floors.

```java
Query query = new Query();
Update update = new Update();

events.forEach(event -> {
    getMaxHeight(update, tripEntity, tenant.toLowerCase());
});

mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, "somecollection");
```

```java
private void getMaxHeight(Update update, Event event) {
    update.max(event.getFloor(), "maxHeight"), event.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't support global variables. Just seeing this bit of code, you did write the code to overwrite it each iteration, so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: my question is: is there a way to use update.max() in such a way, that it's being over written only when event.getHeight() is bigger than previous value. Current implementation will only store the values from last element. global variable = class variable here. sorry about that.

Comment: you mean like adding a conditional statement?

Comment: no, I mean like is it even possible using update(mongodb). Or I just should use map(floor, maxHeight)?

Comment: yes, that is possible by 'adding a conditional statement'.

Comment: ok, but how to store the maximum height for each level?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up moving upsert inside the loop and using max.

```
    events.forEach(event -> {
       Query query = new Query();
       Update update = new Update();
       getMaxHeight(update, tripEntity, tenant.toLowerCase());
       mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, "somecollection");
    });

    private void getMaxHeight(Update update, Event event) {
    update.max(event.getFloor(), "maxHeight"), event.getHeight());
}
```